# JSON file structuring using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

```
[
  {
    "customer": "A",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "B"
      },
      {
        "customer": "B",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "customer": "C",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": "4",
            "name": "E"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "customer": "E",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": "5",
            "name": "F"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "customer": "D",
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and I need my output to be like this, to visualize the data in a tree graph. How can I do this using JavaScript

```
[
  {
    "customer": "A",
    "children": [
      {
        "customer": "B"
      },
      {
        "customer": "C",
        "children": [
          {
            "customer": "E",
            "children": [
              {
                "customer": "F"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and I need my output to be like above, to visualize the data in a tree graph. How can I do that using JavaScript and I need my output to be like above, to visualize the data in a tree graph? How can I do that using JavaScript?

Comment: where is the difference? please remove the superfluous whitespace and add the code, you tried.

Comment: Could you explain the rules for transforming the input to the output; it's not clear why you'd expect the output you gave us.

Comment: @Jacob There is no rule

Comment: @NinaScholz 

seemed like a simple task but I'm finding it hard to achieve. I have object containing child objects, and while looping over them i would like to delete child properties(id and name)

Comment: Is your sample input correct, or all customers supposed to be at the top level of the array and the `children` arrays are all `{ id, name }` pairs? Currently your question is confusing because the data structure isn't explained and looks to be inconsistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making a big assumption here, but I suspect what you really meant is that your sample input actually has this shape:

```
const customers = [
  {
    "customer": "A",
    "children": [{ "id": "1", "name": "B" }]
  },
  {
    "customer": "B",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "customer": "C",
    "children": [{ "id": "4", "name": "E" }]
  },
  {
    "customer": "E",
    "children": [{ "id": "5", "name": "F" }]
  },
  {
    "customer": "D",
    "children": []
  }
]
```

...and you want to nest all the child records with a given `name` with a matching customer record where `name === customer`.

I'm making this assumption because the input format you posted is inconsistent in what is contained in the children arrays, so either the input data is super weird or you made a typo when posting it.

Assuming I'm correct, my approach would be to make a pass through all the customers and make a few maps. One will be a map of `parent -> children`, and the other will be `child -> parent`. The first will help us build our output tree. The second will help us know which customer(s) should appear at the top (they don't have a parent):

```
const childrenLookup = new Map(); // string -> [string]
const parentLookup = new Map();   // string -> string
for (const { customer: parent, children: childRefs } of customers) {
  const children = childRefs.map(c => c.name);
  childrenLookup.set(parent, children);
  for (const child of children) {
    parentLookup.set(child, parent);
  }
}
```

Now that we have some lookups, we can start looping through customers that are not a child of another customer and build our tree using a recursive function

```
function buildOutput(customers) {
  return customers.map(customer => {
    const result = { customer };
    const children = childrenLookup.get(customer);
    if (children && children.length) {
      result.children = buildOutput(children) 
    }
    return result;
  });
}

const allCustomers = [...childrenLookup.keys()];
const topLevelCustomers = allCustomers.filter(cust => !parentLookup.has(cust));

const result = buildOutput(topLevelCustomers);
```

With the given input, you'll now get the output:

```
[
  {
    customer: "A",
    children: [
      {customer: "B"}
    ]
  },
  {
    customer:"C",
    children: [
      {customer: "E", children":[
        {customer:"F"}
      ]}
    ]
  },
  {"customer":"D"}
]
```